# Tracking distance with "distanceBetween" is wrong and driving me nuts

Tags: android, gps, tracking, distance

I have trouble with the tracking of a driven distance.
I tried it like in this article: [Source-Code is completely also there](http://www.krvarma.com/2010/06/programming-gps-on-android-and-calculating-distance-between-two-geographic-locations/)

The SUM of the driven distance is not the real driven distance that is displayed in my car.
After 2-3 km, I have a difference between my displayed distance in my car and the app of 200-800 meters. In this short distance :o)
What I also recognized is that the distance, e.g. while driving curves, is decrementing.
I have also tried several values for minTime and minDistance for the listener, but no success.

What I am doing wrong?
When I use the "MyTracks" app, the driven distance is caculated really, really fine and correct.
I only need a way to sum the completely driven way from start to end, without displaying it in google maps. Is this really so complicated?

kind regards
Frank

OK, the interesting part of the code:

```
public void startListening(final Activity activity)
    {
            if (locationManager == null)
            {
                    locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            }

            final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
            criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

            final String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            if (bestProvider != null && bestProvider.length() > 0)
            {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, GPSManager.gpsMinTime,
                                    GPSManager.gpsMinDistance, locationListener);
            }
            else
            {
                    final List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);

                    for (final String provider : providers)
                    {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, GPSManager.gpsMinTime,
                                            GPSManager.gpsMinDistance, locationListener);
                    }
            }
    }
```

and:

```
private double calcGeoDistance(final double lat1, final double lon1, final double lat2, final double lon2)
    {
            double distance = 0.0;

            try
            {
                    final float[] results = new float[3];

                    Location.distanceBetween(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, results);

                    distance = results[0];
            }
            catch (final Exception ex)
            {
                    distance = 0.0;
            }

            return distance;
    }
```

and:

```
private void updateMeasurement(){
            double distance = calcGeoDistance(startLat,startLon,currentLat,currentLon) * multipliers[unitindex];
            String distanceText = "" + RoundDecimal(distance,2) + " " + unitstrings[unitindex];

            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.distance)).setText(distanceText);
    }
```

and:

```
public double RoundDecimal(double value, int decimalPlace)
    {
            BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);

            bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace, 6);

            return bd.doubleValue();
    }
```

Ohhh, and as I am writing this down it seems that the distance is caculated between the start point and the current point. Not between the last two measurements with the sum of all values, right?

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code.  The link you provided is not enough.

Are you sure you've got LAT and LONG the right way round?

distanceBetween calculates using an approximation of a great circle route so comparing with a straight line will introduce increasing errors as the distance increases (unless you drive great circles ;)).  Your error is in the order of 10% so suggests a coding error.

Comment: OK, figured it out by myself.
The calculation was doing in relation to the starting point.
I changed it to the previous measurement and sum the values.
Seems to be running now.
Will try it tomorrow morning on my way to work :)

Answer (score 0):

With the Criteria that you specify, you're likely to get innacurate locations.  Increase the power requirement.  Also, pay attention to the name of the provider being returned.  If you want accuracy, then you're going to want the GPS provider.

See the following link for more information:
[I keep getting an inaccurate location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196664/gps-is-horribly-inaccurate-in-android)